# How to merge two ECR images of different architectures into one image

Tags: docker, amazon-ecr

In ECR I have `foo:arm` and `foo:amd` I want to upload a new image `foo:latest`

I have tried:

```
docker manifest create foo:latest foo:arm foo:amd
```

But I just get the error:

> foo:arm is a manifest list

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The error message you're receiving indicates that foo:arm and foo:amd are already manifest lists (multi-arch images), which means they are not the actual images for each architecture but rather a list pointing to the images for different architectures. A manifest list is essentially a list of image layers per architecture.

Comment: oh interesting - is there a way i can find the actual image (via cli) so that I can actually create a new tag to be used by both arm and amd nodes?

Comment: Yes! If you already have a manifest list (like foo:arm seems to be), and you want to find out the actual images (digests) it refers to for different architectures, you can use the "docker manifest inspect" command.